# Web services calls in javascript button

Tags: webservices, custom-button

I have a custom button that runs a web service call for an Apex class that makes a SOAP call to an external application. The problem is that this process is executed on the main thread and ends up crashing the browser.
Anyone know how I do not catch the user's screen? Already try to put web worker can not import the libraries:
apex.js
connection.js

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Queueable Apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) and [Queueable Interface](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm) you can use JS to make a call and to make the call asynchronously.